# Jetbrains Datagrip / PHPStorm how to execute an oracle Procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm trying both softwares using thin client (jdbc). My database is oracle (v9 and v11g). The problem is that I can't find a way to execute a procedure. I have try:

```
execute schema.package.procedure('lorem', :a); -- Like TOAD
execute schema.package.procedure('lorem'); 
execute package.procedure('lorem'); 
execute package.procedure('lorem', :a); -- Also Like TOAD
```

Nothing works. Always the same message:
[2016-01-04 12:40:12] [42000][900] ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: I think I found a way using call
    `call schema.package.procedure('lorem');`  Still can't make return a cursor.

Comment: Have you test plugins database navigator ?

Comment: Executing a procedure is such a basic function that I don't think that installing a plugin should really be necessary. (I will install it to give it a try)
I hope this great IDE can improve on oracle. That should be the missing function to finally replace TOAD.

Comment: do you know a free DB oracle with procedure ? I want to try also for help you but a don't have Oracle RDBMS on work and home.... :(

Comment: I think Oracle has a free version to study or develop. But don't waste your time. I'm using oracle at work but if I had to choose a DB to work, oracle is not my first option. May be the last one. It's a strong database but connectors and other stuff are a pain in the ahhhhh!

Comment: I think that Datagrip has everything you will find in jetBrains IDEs (like PHPStorm, etc.). There is a [feature request for PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-625). I think you are not the only one Asking for this feature.

Answer (score 5):

DataGrip allows to execute stored procedure without parameters in current schema like this:

```
call some_proc();
```

Here is how to call proc with params from other schema:

```
call schema.package.procedure('params');
```

Comment: what about stores with out parameters that return a table or resultset.?